# How to style mat table on hover like figma design attached

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have a design for a mat-table. find the attached image. on hover, the row should look like the attached image

[figma design on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oy88B.png)
[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n8gr1n?file=src/app/table/table.component.scss)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a wrapper in table cells to do this styling. Here is the attached example of what you are trying to do

https://angular-w5ynyb.stackblitz.io

Editor
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w5ynyb